# Error: Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed

Tags: solidity

I'm developing a Smart contract. In this Smart contract, I have one method called 'put' which creates a new Type when it doesn't exists and then adds it to a mapping (name <-> type). But after compiling, I get an error (see below). Here's my code:

```
struct Type {
    string name;
    mapping(address => string[]) clients;
}

mapping(string => Type) types;

function put(string memory name, string memory message) public {
    Type storage _type = types[name];
    if (keccak256(abi.encode(_type.name)) == keccak256(abi.encode(""))) {
        // if empty, create new struct, else retrieve and use the old one
        Type storage newType = Type();
        newType.name = name;
        _type.clients[msg.sender].push(message);
        types[name] = newType;
    } else {
        _type.clients[msg.sender].push(message);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to create a Type struct when one doesn't already exist, but when I compile the Smart contract. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed.
  --> project:/contracts/ContractTest.sol:16:36:
   |
16 |             Type storage newType = Type();
   |                                    ^^^^^^
```

I was also wondering if my if statement that checks if the Struct is empty is necessary?

Comment: This has already been asked on SO: [Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed. in solidity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68723493/struct-containing-a-nested-mapping-cannot-be-constructed-in-solidity). See my answer there.

Comment: "I was also wondering if my if statement that checks if the Struct is empty is necessary?" It is if you don't want to overwrite an existing entry. You don't necessarily have to store the name itself there though (unless you need it for another purpose). The mapping key guarantees that the name matches so you could just use a boolean flag. Or, if you know that message count will always be non-zero, you could check that instead.